# Combine two asp.net web site into one

Tags: c#, asp.net, local, host

i am new in asp.net i dont know to how to combine two asp.net web site into one like domain and subdomain concept.
i know the procedure to host one web application in local iis. Please explain the how to combine two application and how to host in local iis i.e) single url as domain(one web application) and subdomain(another web application).

The url should be like these:

1. http://localhost/firstapplication/
2. http://localhost/secondapplication.firstapplication/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question but I think what you want to do is setup a host header for 2 different applications so that you can access them from the same IIS instance. Here is an article that shows you how to configure the hosts:

[Using Host Headers to host multiple websites on IIS 6.0](http://www.gafvert.info/iis/article/iis_multiple_websites.htm)

If you are testing this locally you probably want to make a host file entry to simulate the environment.

If you want it to be localhost/firstapplication and localhost/secondapplication.firstapplication/ then you could create a virtual for each application. Here is how you can do that:

[How To Create a Virtual Directory in Internet Information Services (IIS)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138)